# Common Lisp: How to use macro to generate S-expressions for CL-WHO?

Tags: html, common-lisp

Say I have defined a macro for CL-WHO:

```
(defmacro test-html (&body body)
   `(with-html-output-to-string (*standard-output* nil :PROLOGUE t :indent t)
      (:html
       (:body
    ,@body))))
```

Then:

```
(test-html (:h1 "hallo"))
```

Gives (first line removed):

```
"<html>
  <body>
    <h1>
      hallo
    </h1>
  </body>
</html>"
```

As expected. Now I have defined a function to generate the s-expression to be used by CL-WHO:

```
(defun test-header (txt)
  `(:h1 ,txt))
```

When called with "hallo" returns

```
(:h1 "hallo")
```

BUT now when I call

```
(test-html (test-header "hallo"))
```

It returns:

```
"<html>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>"
```

What went wrong and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I tend to solve this problem is by defining a shortcut macro like

```
(defmacro html-to-stout (&body body)
  "Outputs HTML to standard out."
  `(with-html-output (*standard-output* nil :indent t) ,@body))
```

or the string-equivalent. The key here is that it doesn't output a `:prologue`, so it can output an HTML chunklet rather than a full page. Once you've got that, you can do things like

```
(defun test-header (text)
  (html-to-stout 
    (:h1 (str text))))

(test-html (test-header "Hello Hello"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. As far as I could google out was, that it is not possible in the official version of cl-who: http://lisp-univ-etc.blogspot.com/2009/03/cl-who-macros.html

I used this version instead, which supports macros: https://github.com/vseloved/cl-who

Comment: Thanks for the link! It's funny.. after reading the whole article and reaching the comment part, I realized I read this article 2 months ago and left a comment. My memory is failing me -- I'll try out Vsevolod's fork!